# Pyinstaller on Linux - How to show a console

Tags: python, console, pyinstaller

I'm trying to generate a Python executable file with Pyinstaller on Linux. For this purpose I'm trying this implementation with a simple 'Hello World' file.

The issue I'm having is that when the executable file is generated and I execute it (double-click), nothing happens. There is no console popping out and I can see no execution. I have read in the documentation that in MacOS and Windows there are explicit options in order to make this console appear or not, but not in Linux.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't use Linux, but you can execute your bundled app in the terminal. If the program prints some text it should appear there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open your console, and use "python file.py" or "python3 file.py" command (it depends on Python version), where file.py is your file.

I hope that I helped.

Comment: Yes, it definately appears. But I'm trying to obtain an executable that open itselfs a console without having to execute it in the terminal, any idea?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418553/auto-executable-python-file-without-opening-from-terminal)